# ссылка на сайте, а файл на lan или ftp сервере

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp

Поднял дома сайт на wordpress на старом tv-box. Так же дома есть NAS(ftp сервер настроен).

Есть ли возможность разместить ссылку на сайте на файл который хранится на сервере? Как это реализовать? Можно ли как-то добавить эти файлы(их местоположение) в медиатеку сайта?

Расширение решающее эту задачу не нашел.

Comment: А что, просто вставить туда абсолютную ссылку, от хоста и до расширения - не работает? Щёлкнул, перешёл, скачал...

Comment: Вордпресс не запрещает размещать никакие ссылки. Вопрос скорее всего лежит области системного администрирования и не имеет отношения к проставленным тегам

Comment: все перепробовал: ftp//85.88.175.212 это сервер, доступ у него только чтение по протоколу 1025. Разместил там фаил /SharedServer/qwe.txt  при переходе по ссылке открывается доп окно в браузере, появляется вопрос чем открывать? как я понимаю ссылку надо формировать каким-то особым образом. И есть ли возможность добавление этих файлов в медиатеку, чтоб не бегать за адресом хранения.

Comment: @РоманГорчаков Ну так файлы txt достыпны только для скачивания, браузер их не открывает. Если хотите в браузере, то надо в PHP/WP их читать и выдавать контент, т.е через сервер пропускать

Comment: В медиатеку можно загрузить любой файл, если сделать поддержку нужных расширений (для этого есть плагины, если нужно). Но загрузить - не значит что браузер отобразит, как выше верно заметили. Если нужно отображать содержимое txt файлов, то это совершено другой вопрос.